# When a user clicks on the legend in a graph show the respective graph element instead of hiding it

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When a user clicks on a legend in a graph, today we hide the respective element in the graph. The behavior should be just the opposite. When a user clicks on a legend, the graph should hide all the elements except the element related to the legend. If the user wants to see multiple elements (lets say lines or bars) on the graph, then he/she should press "Ctrl" key and then click the multiple legends to see the respective elements on the graph. This lets the user to achieve the behavior of looking just at one element (bar, line etc ) or compare the ones he/she wants by clicking the respective legends by holding the "Ctrl" key.

Would like to know whether I can achieve the above behaviour in highcharts or not.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can achieved by setting [legendItemClick](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series%3Cline%3E.gapSize/plotOptions.area.events.legendItemClick) and in that events hiding all series except the clicked one or if the ctrl is pressed do some other action - see fidle http://jsfiddle.net/q0mwfg1a/ (in the fiddle firing event will start if you first click on the span - with false element)

Comment: Thanks  @morganfree. Your inputs helped me.